# establishing relationship between data in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-relationship

i have a method that will populate a datatable with the data from a sql table which in turn would be used to populate a gridview. Now in the sql table i have a field called "hotel" which contains the "ID" of a hotel which relates to another table called "hotels" with hotel id and name.

Now in my grid view i want to display the hotel name instead of the hotel id. How can i do it.

```
 public static DataTable GetRequests(string empid)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connStr"];
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataAdapter sAdap = new SqlDataAdapter();                
                sqlcmd.Connection = connection;
                sqlcmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                sqlcmd.CommandText = "Select request_date,hotel,dining_date,status from requests Where emp_id='" + empid + "'";
                sAdap.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;
                sAdap.Fill(dt);
            }
            return dt;            
        }
```

This is the method that retrieves the records. The hotel field contains the ID for which i want the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to your sql query and thing will work out.

Let us say 'Hotel' which contain hotel id and in the another table 'HotelDetails which contain the hotel id and hotel name.

Table structure of Hotel
  HotelId int
Table structure of HotelDetails
  HotelId int,
  HotelName varchar(10)

Now you query should be

```
SELECT b.HotelName as HotelName, c.request_date as RequestDate,c.dining_date as DiningDate ,c.status as Status FROM Hotel a, HotelDetails b, requests c WHERE a.HotelId = b.HotelId and emp_id='" + empid + "'
```

In the GridView, your DataFild should be HotelName in order to display Hotel Name

For instance

```
<Columns>
                                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Slno">
                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                                <ControlStyle Width="30px" />
                                                                <ItemStyle ForeColor="#00846F" Width="30px" />
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-Width="90" DataField="HotelName" 
                                                                HeaderText="Hotel Name" ItemStyle-ForeColor="#00846F" 
                                                                ItemStyle-Width="30">
                                                                <ControlStyle Width="30px" />
                                                                <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
                                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                                            <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-ForeColor="#00846F" ControlStyle-Width="190" 
                                                                DataField="RequestDate" HeaderText="Request Date" 
                                                                ItemStyle-ForeColor="#00846F" ItemStyle-Width="100">
                                                                <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
                                                                <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                                            <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-ForeColor="#00846F" ControlStyle-Width="100" 
                                                                DataField="DiningDate" HeaderText="Dining Date" 
                                                                ItemStyle-ForeColor="#00846F" ItemStyle-Width="50">
                                                                <ControlStyle Width="50px" />
                                                                <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                                            <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-ForeColor="#00846F" ControlStyle-Width="100" 
                                                                DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                                                                ItemStyle-ForeColor="#00846F" ItemStyle-Width="50">
                                                                <ControlStyle Width="50px" />
                                                                <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                                            </asp:BoundField>



                                                        </Columns>
```

If you find it useful, please mark it as your answer else let me know....

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx).